# Iterate over non-persistent activemq expired messages in ActiveMQ.Advisory.Expired.Queue

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Iam building an application on activemq where iam sending a message from producer where my delivery mode is NON_PERSISTENT (**iam not dealing with PERSISTENT delivery mode and i know it will be stored in DLQ-which is not my design**)and have set a time to live for the message using producer.setTimeToLive(2000).As the functionality says the message will expire in 2 seconds.

I see that the expired messages are enqueued in the **ActiveMQ.Advisory.Expired.Queue** in the topic section of activeMQ admin console i.e. **http://localhost:8161/admin/topics.jsp**.

My question is how do i iterate over the **ActiveMQ.Advisory.Expired.Queue** so that i can access the **MessageID** of the expired message.Any code example would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subscription to the destination **ActiveMQ.Advisory.Expired.Queue** is like any topic and it returns an ActiveMQMessage. 
There is DataStructure objects (ConsumerInfo, ProducerInfo,ConnectionInfo...) can be retrieve via getDataStructure method of ActiveMQMessage.

doc http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html

example:

```
Destination advisoryDestination = AdvisorySupport.getExpiredQueueMessageAdvisoryTopic(destination)
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(advisoryDestination);
consumer.setMessageListener(this);

public void onMessage(Message msg){
    String messageId =   msg.getJMSMessageID();
    String orignalMessageId =   msg.getStringProperty(org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisorySupport.MSG_PROPERTY_MESSAGE_ID);
    if (msg instanceof ActiveMQMessage){
        try {
             ActiveMQMessage aMsg =  (ActiveMQMessage)msg;
             ProducerInfo prod = (ProducerInfo) aMsg.getDataStructure();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.error("Failed to process message: " + msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hassen Bennour By use the above code I can able to receive the messages which is expires after the message listener starts. I cannot receive previously expired messages which is resides in **DLQ**. How can I iterate and get the previously expired message? For my concern i need those messages also.

Comment: you can try to add this policy to your topics to use a Queue instead of topic as a DLQ, like this messages will not be lost if there is no consumer online, the key is **useQueueForTopicMessages**  
`<destinationPolicy>
 <policyMap>
   <policyEntries>
  <policyEntry topic=">" >
   <deadLetterStrategy>
    <individualDeadLetterStrategy  processNonPersistent="true" processExpired="true"  useQueueForTopicMessages="true" />
   </deadLetterStrategy>
  </policyEntry>
   </policyEntries>
 </policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>`

Comment: note that by using **useQueueForTopicMessages** the answer code is not possible for this use case, you need to consume from the DLQ queue as any queue.